# Zeppelin 0.8.2 - localRepoPath should have a value

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm getting this error message, when trying to run Spark interpreter from Zepplein 0.8.2

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: localRepoPath should have a value
    at org.apache.commons.lang.Validate.notNull(Validate.java:192)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.dep.Booter.newRepositorySystemSession(Booter.java:43)
```

simple command

```
print(sc)
```

Excepiton source is here: https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/70b4ec84f51593e0e7a64b55b51ac96946bed299/zeppelin-interpreter/src/main/java/org/apache/zeppelin/dep/Booter.java#L43

My home dir:

```
echo $ZEPPELIN_HOME
/usr/local/zeppelin
```

Any idea what can cause the problem?

additional info:

```
master  yarn
spark.submit.deployMode cluster
spark.yarn.jars hdfs:///spark-lib/*.jar - spark submit works ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I just hit the same issue so for the benefit of anyone who comes after sharing my "fix".

I was able to get past this by setting *zeppelin.dep.localrepo* to */tmp* in the spark interpreter settings. Seems it just didn't like there being an invalid path in there. See https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.8.0/interpreter/spark.html for a list of properties.